# Search and replace text across all posts

Tags: plugins, search, mysql, query

I had used the ZD Video Plugin for WP a long time, and now, since my move to WP 3.0.2, it doesn't work anymore. To embed a YouTube video using the plugin, I would just write

> [zdvideo]url-of-youtube-video[/zdvideo]

Now I need to go back to plain YouTube embedding. How do I write a MySQL query that searches for `[zdvideo]*[zdvideo]` and replaces it with `*`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about these two queries?

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '[zdvideo]', '');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '[/zdvideo]', '');
```

Comment: That'll only work if entering the YouTube URL is enough for his purpose. If there are things like `<div>[zdvideo]...[/zdvideo]</div>` the oEmbed functionality will be broken.

Comment: @Denis: If he wants to use the oEmbed stuff, I think you can also replace `[zdvideo]` with `[embed]`, which will work even if the URL is not on a single line.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Now if I want to replace all instances of `http://youtube.com` with `httpv://youtube.com`, I can use the `REPLACE` function as shown above, right?

Answer (score 5):

Best I'm aware, MySQL doesn't have much of a regexp replace functionality -- not to mention its very clunky regexp syntax. So this is easiest to do at the php level. Start by fetching all posts that have the shortcode:

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT ID, post_content
FROM $wpdb->posts
WHERE post_content LIKE '%[zdvideo]%'
");
```

And then loop through the result:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
  $post->post_content = preg_replace(
    "/\\[zdvideo\\](.+?)\\[\\/zdvideo\\]/",
    "$1", # $1 holds the url... format as needed
    $post->post_content);

  # Be sure to verify on a few posts before actually saving...
  # var_dump($post->post_content);

  $wpdb->query("
  UPDATE $wdpb->posts
  SET post_content = '" . $wpdb->escape($post->post_content) . "'
  WHERE ID = " . intval($post->ID)
  );
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `$wpdb->escape($post->post_content)` be wrapped in single quotes? Then the whole row would be something like..................................................................................................................................... `SET post_content = '" . $wpdb->escape($post->post_content) . "'`

Comment: @jave.web: good catch.

Comment: NP, otherwise I used this approach in my solution and it works - so I can confirm this approach works :)

Answer (score 1):

or use the plugin [Search & Replace](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/), makes easy for use sql inside WP; use the like statement and give you an gui for search/replace strings in content and other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`wp search-replace`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/).

> Searches through all rows in a selection of tables and replaces
> appearances of the first string with the second string.

[WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) is the command-line interface for WordPress. You can update plugins, configure multisite installations and much more, without using a web browser.