# MySQL: Possible to replace all of wp_posts.post_content(id#) via UPDATE + REPLACE + SELECT?

Tags: posts, mysql, updates, customization

**EDIT:** I want to update one field (post_content) within a known record (id of 4) of a known table (wp_posts) in a new database (new_db).  The update has to come from one field (post_content) within a known record (id of 5) of a known table (wp_posts) in the *old* database (old_db).
Is this possible, or is something like this too atomic (?) for MySQL?

Greetingz!
When manipulating WordPress's database directly, I've seen [many examples here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4918/search-and-replace-text-across-all-posts) where people replace a URL like so;

```
mysql> UPDATE wp_db.wp_post SET post_content=REPLACE(post_content, 'http://oldsite', 'http://newsite' ) ;
```

However, I have a .sql dump file from my old site, that I wish to import correctly.  (I cannot create an XML export file, it's too late)
I have created "dummy" posts on my new blog, and have imported the old database.
Now I'm trying to do something like this;

```
UPDATE new_db.new SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content,(SELECT post_content FROM old_db.wp_posts WHERE id = oldpost#) WHERE id = newpost#;
```

I realize I'll have to do this for post_date, post_title, and post_content between old_db.wp_posts and new_db.posts, I'm just hoping this is actually possible somehow....

Comment: You'll also have to update wp_postmeta and wp_term_relationships, plus wp_comments and wp_commentmeta if there are any comments. Look at http://codex.wordpress.org/File:WP3.0-ERD.png for the structure of the db. Why can't you import everything into an empty WP install, then export the posts in a more logical way? That might be easier if you're dealing with a large number of entries to import.

Comment: I've made new posts into the new blog via QuickPress, so wp_postmeta, wp_term_relationships, and anything comment-related is out of the question.

I'm only dealing with 30 or so posts. But I'm trying to develop a way that will scale to our other blog with 1500 published posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like trying to put "field X" into db.table.record.fieldY is too atomic, or requires a better magic wand than google can find.  I've gone a head and just ripped the posts out wholesale and injected them into the new DB. 
Here's how I did it.  I hope it helps the next poor sod who finds himself in the same place I was...

**How to rip out and inject WordPress posts from an old database into a new one.**

**0)** Make a backup first of the new DB.

```
mysqldump -u root -p new_db >> dump-new_db-datetime.sql
```

**1)** first, find all your old published posts & pages;

```
SELECT id,post_date,post_title FROM old_db.old_posts WHERE
 post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY id;
```

**2)** Delete all your revisions with;

```
DELETE FROM old_posts WHERE post_type = "revision";
```

**3)** inject your old posts & pages into the new DB

```
INSERT INTO new_db.new_posts
  (
  post_author,
  post_date,
  post_date_gmt,
  post_content,
  post_title,
  post_excerpt,
  post_status,
  comment_status,
  ping_status,
  post_password,
  post_name,
  to_ping,
  pinged,
  post_modified,
  post_modified_gmt,
  post_content_filtered,
  post_parent,
  guid,
  menu_order,
  post_type,
  post_mime_type,
  comment_count
  )
SELECT
  old_posts.post_author,
  old_posts.post_date,
  old_posts.post_date_gmt,
  old_posts.post_content,
  old_posts.post_title,
  old_posts.post_excerpt,
  old_posts.post_status,
  old_posts.comment_status,
  old_posts.ping_status,
  old_posts.post_password,
  old_posts.post_name,
  old_posts.to_ping,
  old_posts.pinged,
  old_posts.post_modified,
  old_posts.post_modified_gmt,
  old_posts.post_content_filtered,
  old_posts.post_parent,
  old_posts.guid,
  old_posts.menu_order,
  old_posts.post_type,
  old_posts.post_mime_type,
  old_posts.comment_count
FROM old_db.old_posts;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible what you want in an easy way. Have a look at http://spectacu.la/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/; that will do all replaces automatically while also keeping length specifications of serialized data correct.
Cheers,
Peter

Comment: Peter, I appreciate the link. However the script is designed to replace strings within any table of any database (by default).  However I do like how it treats serialized data (more stuff for me to google).

I'm looking to replace a record's post_content as a whole, from old_db.wp_posts(id=1) to new_db.wp_posts(id=5).